# OpenErp Server Error

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I am new to openerp. I was able to log on. I tried on gunicorp and now I am unable to log in.

Even If I don't use gunicorp I still get the below error:

Pls advice what might be going wrong.

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 180, in dispatch
response["result"] = method(controller, self, **self.params)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 353, in   
get_list
dbs = proxy.list()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/openerplib/main.py", line 117,  
in proxy
result = self.connector.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 611, in send
raise fault


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 592, in send
result = openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 360, in dispatch_rpc
result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 117, in dispatch
return fn(*params)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 310, in exp_list
cr = db.cursor()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 465, in cursor
return Cursor(self._pool, self.dbname, serialized=serialized)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 173, in __init__
self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn(dbname))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 366, in _locked
return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 421, in borrow
result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: FATAL:  role "vishal" does not exist
```

thank you,
vishal

Answer (score 5):

Basically it looks like you should double-check your database configuration.

The database-level error mentions the fact that the "vishal" user you are using to connect to PostgreSQL does not exist. Perhaps you changed the db_user configuration while testing gunicorn deployment, or you are trying to run OpenERP as the "vishal" system user while you were using another system user previously.

Comment: the problem can be solved by just creating a new role. its explained quite clearly in the openerp documentation( installation manual). just type the following commands in the console for eg:                                                                 sudo su - postgres

Code:
createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --pwprompt openerp
Enter password for new role: ********
Enter it again: ********